# Spark connector: Partition usage and performance issue

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am trying to run a spark job (which talks to Cassandra) to read data, do some aggregation, and then write aggregates to Cassandra

- I have 2 tables (monthly_active_users (MAU) , daily_user_metric_aggregates (DUMA))
- For every record in MAU, there will be one or more records in DUMA
- Get every records in MAU and fetch user_id in it then find records in DUMA for that user (with server side filters applied like metric_name in ('ms', 'md')
- If one or more records in DUMA for the specified where clause then i need to increment the count of appMauAggregate map (app wise MAU counts)
- I tested this algorithm, works as expected but i wanted to find out

1) Is it an optimized algorithm (or) is there any better way to do it? I have a sense that something is not correct and i am not seeing speedups. Looks like Cassandra client is being created and shutdown for each spark action (collect). Takes long time to process small dataset.

2) Spark workers are not co-located with cassandra, meaning spark worker is running in different node (container) than C* node (we may move spark worker to C* node for data locality)

3) I am seeing spark job is being created/submitted for every spark action (collect) and i belive that it is an expected behavior from spark, is there anyway to cutdown reads from C* and create joins so that data retrierval is fast?

4) What is the downside of this algorithm? Can you recommend better design approach, meaning w/r/t partition strategy, loading C* partition onto Spark partition, executor's / driver's memory requirement?

5) As long as algorithm and design approach is fine then i can play around with spark tuning. I am using 5 workers (each with 16 CPU and 64GB RAM)

### C* Schema :

### MAU:

```
CREATE TABLE analytics.monthly_active_users ( 
    month text, 
    app_id uuid,
    user_id uuid, 
    PRIMARY KEY (month, app_id, user_id) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (app_id ASC, user_id ASC)
```

### data:

```
cqlsh:analytics> select * from monthly_active_users limit 2;   
 month  | app_id                               | user_id 

--------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------- 
 2015-2 | 108eeeb3-7ff1-492c-9dcd-491b68492bf2 | 199c0a31-8e74-46d9-9b3c-04f67d58b4d1 
 2015-2 | 108eeeb3-7ff1-492c-9dcd-491b68492bf2 | 2c70a31a-031c-4dbf-8dbd-e2ce7bdc2bc7
```

### DUMA:

```
CREATE TABLE analytics.daily_user_metric_aggregates ( 
    metric_date timestamp, 
    user_id uuid,
    metric_name text, 
    "count" counter, 
    PRIMARY KEY (metric_date, user_id, metric_name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (user_id ASC, metric_name ASC)
```

### data:

```
cqlsh:analytics> select * from daily_user_metric_aggregates where metric_date='2015-02-08' and user_id=199c0a31-8e74-46d9-9b3c-04f67d58b4d1; 
 metric_date | user_id                                                         | metric_name       | count 
--------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+------- 
 2015-02-08 | 199c0a31-8e74-46d9-9b3c-04f67d58b4d1 | md                      |     1     
 2015-02-08 | 199c0a31-8e74-46d9-9b3c-04f67d58b4d1 | ms                      |     1
```

### Spark Job :

```
import java.net.InetAddress 
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong 
import java.util.{Date, UUID} 

import com.datastax.spark.connector.util.Logging 
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext} 
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone} 

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer 

object MonthlyActiveUserAggregate extends App with Logging { 

    val KeySpace: String = "analytics" 
    val MauTable: String = "mau" 

    val CassandraHostProperty = "CASSANDRA_HOST" 
    val CassandraDefaultHost = "127.0.0.1" 
    val CassandraHost = InetAddress.getByName(sys.env.getOrElse(CassandraHostProperty, CassandraDefaultHost)) 

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(getClass.getSimpleName) 
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", CassandraHost.getHostAddress) 

    lazy val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
    import com.datastax.spark.connector._ 

    def now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC) 
    val metricMonth = now.getYear + "-" + now.getMonthOfYear 

    private val mauMonthSB: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder 
    mauMonthSB.append(now.getYear).append("-") 
    if (now.getMonthOfYear < 10) mauMonthSB.append("0") 
    mauMonthSB.append(now.getMonthOfYear).append("-") 
    if (now.getDayOfMonth < 10) mauMonthSB.append("0") 
    mauMonthSB.append(now.getDayOfMonth) 

    private val mauMonth: String = mauMonthSB.toString() 

    val dates = ListBuffer[String]() 
    for (day <- 1 to now.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue) { 
        val metricDate: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder 
        metricDate.append(now.getYear).append("-") 
        if (now.getMonthOfYear < 10) metricDate.append("0") 
        metricDate.append(now.getMonthOfYear).append("-") 
        if (day < 10) metricDate.append("0") 
        metricDate.append(day) 
        dates += metricDate.toString() 
    } 

    private val metricName: List[String] = List("ms", "md") 
    val appMauAggregate = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, scala.collection.mutable.Map[UUID, AtomicLong]]() 

    case class MAURecord(month: String, appId: UUID, userId: UUID) extends Serializable 
    case class DUMARecord(metricDate: Date, userId: UUID, metricName: String) extends Serializable 
    case class MAUAggregate(month: String, appId: UUID, total: Long) extends Serializable 

    private val mau = sc.cassandraTable[MAURecord]("analytics", "monthly_active_users") 
        .where("month = ?", metricMonth) 
        .collect() 

    mau.foreach { monthlyActiveUser => 
        val duma = sc.cassandraTable[DUMARecord]("analytics", "daily_user_metric_aggregates") 
            .where("metric_date in ? and user_id = ? and metric_name in ?", dates, monthlyActiveUser.userId, metricName) 
            //.map(_.userId).distinct().collect() 
            .collect() 

        if (duma.length > 0) { // if user has `ms` for the given month 
            if (!appMauAggregate.isDefinedAt(mauMonth)) { 
                appMauAggregate += (mauMonth -> scala.collection.mutable.Map[UUID, AtomicLong]()) 
            } 
            val monthMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[UUID, AtomicLong] = appMauAggregate(mauMonth) 
            if (!monthMap.isDefinedAt(monthlyActiveUser.appId)) { 
                monthMap += (monthlyActiveUser.appId -> new AtomicLong(0)) 
            } 
            monthMap(monthlyActiveUser.appId).incrementAndGet() 
        } else { 
            println(s"No message_sent in daily_user_metric_aggregates for user: $monthlyActiveUser") 
        } 

    } 
    for ((metricMonth: String, appMauCounts: scala.collection.mutable.Map[UUID, AtomicLong]) <- appMauAggregate) { 
        for ((appId: UUID, total: AtomicLong) <- appMauCounts) { 
            println(s"month: $metricMonth, app_id: $appId, total: $total"); 
            val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(MAUAggregate(metricMonth.substring(0, 7), appId, total.get()))) 
            collection.saveToCassandra(KeySpace, MauTable, SomeColumns("month", "app_id", "total")) 
        } 
    } 
    sc.stop() 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the least efficient possible. You are performing a join by looking up each key one-by-one, avoiding any possible parallelization.

I've never used the Cassandra connector, but I understand it returns RDDs. So you could do this:

```
val mau: RDD[(UUID, MAURecord)] = sc
    .cassandraTable[MAURecord]("analytics", "monthly_active_users") 
    .where("month = ?", metricMonth)
    .map(u => u.userId -> u)  // Key by user ID.
val duma: RDD[(UUID, DUMARecord)] = sc
    .cassandraTable[DUMARecord]("analytics", "daily_user_metric_aggregates") 
    .where("metric_date in ? metric_name in ?", dates, metricName)
    .map(a => a.userId -> a)  // Key by user ID.
// Count "duma" by key.
val dumaCounts: RDD[(UUID, Long)] = duma.countByKey
// Join to "mau". This drops "mau" entries that have no count
// and "duma" entries that are not present in "mau".
val joined: RDD[(UUID, (MAURecord, Long))] = mau.join(dumaCounts)
// Get per-application counts.
val appCounts: RDD[(UUID, Long)] = joined
    .map { case (u, (mau, count)) => mau.appId -> 1 }
    .countByKey
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a parameter spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms which controls for how long keep the connection opened. Take a look at the documentation [page](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md).
2. If you colocate Spark Workers with Cassandra nodes, connector will take advantage of this and create partitions appropriately so that the executor will always fetch data from the local node.

I can see some design improvements you can make in DUMA table: metric_date seems to be not the best choice for partition key - consider making (user_id, metric_name) a partition key because in that case you will not have to generate dates for the query - you will just need to put user_id and metrics_name to the where clause. Moreover, you can add a month identifier to the primary key - then, each partition will include only those information which are related to what you want to fetch with each query.

Anyway, the functionality of join in Spark-Cassandra-Connector are currently being implemented (see [this ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-25)).